# Unresolved external symbol,confused

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

I have a median function that finds a median from elements of the array as follows

**median.h**

```
template <class N>
N median (N*,size_t);
```

**median.cpp**

```
#include "median.h"
template <class N> 
 N median (N* numbers,size_t size){
    size_t mid = size/2;
    return size % 2 == 0? (numbers[mid] + numbers[mid-1])/2 : numbers[mid];
}
```

**main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "median.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double Numbers [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};


    size_t size = sizeof(Numbers)/sizeof(*Numbers);

    double med = median(Numbers,size);
    cout << med << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

But I get the following error

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl median<double>(double *,unsigned int)" (??$median@N@@YANPANI@Z) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574417#12574417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates should instantiated by compiler before they used. In `median.h` you have declaration of `median` template, and in `media.cpp` you have its implementation but you don't use it in that file, so template won't instantiated in that file. On other side on `main.cpp` you try to instantiate template but there is no implementation, just declaration! So compiler will fail to instantiate template's implementation and that's the cause of your error. Just move implementation to `median.h` or instantiate the template in `median.cpp` by using:

```
template double median<double>(double*, size_t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either put an `#include "median.cpp"` into your main or move the implementation of the template into the header file `median.h`

Comment: Include a cpp file? That's one of the worst advises you can give.

Comment: I don't see it as a cpp file, rather than a template implementation file. Care to elaborate, why you think so? A link would be fine, too.

Comment: @Olaf there is absolutely no point in separating template definitions from their declaration - if anything, it could get in the way of inlining when using an insufficiently smart compiler.

Comment: @Cubic it makes code easier to read, so that's one reason, no matter how small you think it is.

Comment: @OlafDietsche then it should be renamed to `.template` or something so that it doesn't get accidentally sent to the compiler as a compilation unit.